# firefox dev tools issue

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using firebug browser and I've written my media queries for mobile view for my website. I have noticed this weird behaviour when using my dev tools's inspect element to test for different mobile screens eg.iphone, the result of my media query only works when I manuallly adjust the browser with my mouse cursor, when I use the dev tools to select phone options, the result is like toggling different desktop views on mobile. Is this normal, how do I stop this behaviour.

**Result without manual adjustment**
http://prnt.sc/s2qkb0

**Result while adjusting browser manually**
https://prnt.sc/s2qnrr

Comment: Hi, we need to see a [mcve] to help; please include at least the media query CSS that you're using. Preferably upload the images to Stack Overflow directly as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered my problem, I did not include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">"
```

in the head section of my website. I may have to start affresh to fix things because my layout is currently scattered because of this.

Comment: Additional Tip: A similar issue also arises when you are delivering a server rendered page, in that case you just have to toggle the "reload when user agent is changed" option.

Comment: you have to toggle the reload, what user agent are you refering to please?